# laravel Rule::exists by connection and column

Tags: laravel-validation, laravel-excel

I am using the [Laravel Excel package](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html) to import data from an Excel spreadsheet file. During the importing, I need to verify that some column values exist in an external database table at a specific column.

The external model `Catalog.php` looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\External\Catalogs;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Catalog extends Model
{
    protected $connection='external';

    protected $table='catalogs';
}
```

Now the `InformationImport.php` MaatWebsite class looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\External\Catalogs\Catalog;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\OnEachRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsUnknownSheets;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Row;

class InformationImport implements OnEachRow, WithValidation, WithHeadingRow, SkipsUnknownSheets, WithMultipleSheets
{
    //...

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'catalog_type'=>'required|max:255',Rule::exists('App\Models\External\Catalogs\Catalog,name'),
        ];
    }

    //...
}
```

The problem is that this part `Rule::exists('App\Models\External\Catalogs\Catalog,name')` is not validating correctly. If there's a value that does not actually exist in that Catalog, there's no error concerning the `exists`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little bit late, but if you use Rule::exists() you have to pass it this way: Rule::exists(App\Models\External\Catalogs\Catalog::class, 'name');

Answer (score 0):

```
return [
            'catalog_type'=>'required|max:255|' . Rule::exists('catalogs_table', 'name')
        ];
```